# python, SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here. Что делать? И почему?

Tags: python

```
def find_missing_letter(chars):
    letter_lower=[]
    for i in range(97,123):
        letter_lower.append(chr(i))
    chars1 = []
    chars_upp = []
    for i in chars:
        chars1.append(i.lower())
    a = letter_lower.index(chars1[0])
    b = letter_lower.index(chars1[-1])
    c = ((set(letter_lower[a:b+1]) - set(chars)))
    if chars[0].islower():
        return f'{chars} -> {c}'
       #return f'{chars} -> {*c}'

print(find_missing_letter(['a','b','c','d','f']))
```

Фрагмент кода, запускается.
Вывод должен быть такого вида:
`["a","b","c","d","f"] -> "e"`
получается так:
`['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f'] -> {'e'}`
Eсли применить распаковку в строке:
`return f'{chars} -> {*c}'` то "SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here".
Задача такая - Напишите метод, который принимает массив последовательных (возрастающих) букв в качестве входных данных и возвращает недостающую букву в массиве.

Comment: Ну потому что такой синтаксической конструкции в f-строках в принципе не существует.

Comment: Если вы хотите вытащить элемент из множества, вот тут описано много способов как это сделать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59825

Comment: `f'{chars} -> {c.pop()}'`

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться методом строк join(). который осуществляет сборку строки из списка A с разделителем S. S.join(A)

```
return f'{chars} -> "{"".join(c)}"'
#['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f'] -> "e"
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]